# how to make a function parameter optional in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
vm.fetchData = ($index) => {

}
```

I want to make `$index` as optional parameter.

Comment: Don't pass the parameter when you call the function?

Comment: If this is just vanilla JS, then you don't have a concept of a function signature that automatically enforces input-- if a function is invoked without parameters passed, the function will execute until it completes or it encounters an error (likely as a result of the missing parameter)-- there is no runtime check in which it will automatically error out from parameters being omitted that it was somehow "expecting".

Comment: Since AngularJS is using vanilla JS: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, how can I create a function with an optional parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225877/in-javascript-how-can-i-create-a-function-with-an-optional-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't explicitly can declare parameters as optional in vanilla JS, you could simply ignore them in the function body:

```js
vm.fetchData = function($index) {
    if(typeof $index == 'undefined') {
      // following should happen if parameter is missing
    } else {
      // following requires a parameter
    }
    
    // do the rest and return 
}
```

See also:

- [How can I check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript#3390426)
- [Is there a better way to do optional function parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript)
- [Set a default parameter value for a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894860/set-a-default-parameter-value-for-a-javascript-function)